# Visualforce button to pre populate a look up field not working

Tags: visualforce, community

I had used the following code.

```
 <div style='text-align:center;padding-bottom:3px;'>
          <form action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_and_Services__c.New,null,['CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_lkid'='{!Account.Id}' , 'CF00N50000003qoqXEAU'='{!Account.Name}'] )}" target="_blank">
          <input type="submit" value="Create New Order"/>
          </form>
          </div>
          <br/>
```

The output is not generating the result. It is blank

[image]

Comment: try `<apex:commandLink value="/a15/e?CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_lkid='{!Account.Id}'&CF00N50000003qoqXEAU='{!Account.Name}'>"`

Comment: you should not use `{!..}` for the parameter values ..simple `Account.id` suffices as you are already within a merge expression (the URLFOR)

Comment: I tried that it is not working the URL for

Comment: I did the following <form action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_and_Services__c.New,null,[CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_l‌​kid=A‌​ccount.Id ,CF00N50000003qoqXEAU=Account.Name] )}" target="_blank" > I got the error " Syntax error"

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct values for the field IDs? A example for a button on the account to create an opp that works is: `{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New,null,[opp4_lkid= Account.Id  ,opp4= Account.Name ])}`. You need to make out the inner ' from the parameters. Otherwise it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to use a form action like you are for this.  Instead, wire up the button to a method on your controller like this.

Controller method:

```
public PageReference createNew(){
  Product_and_Services__c pns = new Product_and_Services__c();
  pns.Account__c = this.account.Id;
  PageReference pr = new ApexPages.StandardController(pns).edit();
  return pr;
}
```

You can replace "this.account.Id" with whatever you have in your controller that's capturing the Id of the account you're viewing.  Basically, you're capturing the account before you try to load the edit page.

And then your button would look like this:

```
<apex:form>
  <apex:commandButton value="Create New Order" action="{!createNew}" />
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Never mind I got it working  <apex:commandLink  value="Create New Order" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_and_Services__c.CreateNewOrder, Id)}" target="_blank" styleClass="btn linkAsBtn" />

Comment: that solution works, but it's not ideal, nor scalable.  If you ever wanted to add more fields then the solution I provided lets you do that.  The best practice solution is the one I posted, just FYI.

Comment: The solution helps in the day to day activites. It is more than enough. Thanks